# add text below menu using css or jquery for all the menus

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add subtitle in the menu. Already subtitle is added but I don't know how it has been added. I want to add same text again in the next line.
check the URL: http://www.hummingbird.se/

In this URL below menu text small sub-title as "Aktuella kampanjer" is added and so on different subtitles have been added.

I tried with css but the down arrow is getting hidden. Is there any other way to do this by using jquery or CSS because Every time I have to add different subtitle below each menu. There is no way to add new class here in the html structure.
I have following code structure:

```
<a href="http://www.hummingbird.se/erbjudanden/">
Erbjudanden
</a>
```

I want structure to be like this :

```
<a href="http://www.hummingbird.se/erbjudanden/">
Erbjudanden
<span class="sub hidden-xs">Aktuella kampanjer</span>
<span class="toggle-submenu"></span>
</a>
```

i tried following css:

```
.sub hidden-xs{
content : 'Aktuella kampanjer';
}
```

Comment: please put u code what u have tried

Comment: I think your questions is poorly phrased Rashmi. Are you swedish? If so feel free to contact me and I will help you out, if you are more comfortable speaking swedish that is.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: i have edited my question. plz help

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the `content:'text here'` CSS to work it needs to be included on a pseudo element; either `a:before { }` or `a:after { }`.

This will create a new pseudo-element inside your `<a href="http://www.hummingbird.se/erbjudanden/">Erbjudanden</a>` link, and you can then give that element styling and text content. e.g.

```
a:before {
    content: 'Aktuella kampanjer';
}
```

The `:before` or `:after` elements technically exist within the link though, so if you click on them you're essentially clicking on the link too, which may not be the behaviour you're looking for.

If your issue is getting the different subtitles onto each item you can use data attributes on the link to pass different values to your content property. e.g.

```
<a href="http://www.hummingbird.se/erbjudanden/"
   data-subtitle="Aktuella kampanjer"
>Erbjudanden</a>
<a href="http://www.hummingbird.se/different_link/"
   data-subtitle="Different subtitle"
>Erbjudanden</a>

a:before {
    content: attr(data-subtitle);
}
```

You could then place the different subtitles straight in your single link of link markup, but control where and how they appear independantly.

Comment: For every menu, the menu subtitle is different. I do not have access to html structure. I can only use Whatever the html is defined and the existing class.